# Matlab - How to binarize a grayscale image with multiple thresholds?

Tags: matlab, threshold, binary-image

I am trying to convert a grayscale image into a binary image with two thresholds:

- img = a grayscale image
- b = the output binary image
- if (img > t1) or (img < t2) then b = 1
- otherwise b = 0

```matlab
t1 = 200;
t2 = 100;
src = imread('an rgb image');
img = reg2gray(src);
b1 = imbinarize(img, t1);
b2 = imbinarize(img, -t2);
b = imadd(b1,b2);
```

but this code doesn't work. Is there a way to set multiple thresholds at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conditional statement can be applied to the array.  When the condition is true the values of the initialized array are set to 1 and the rest of the cells of the array are set to 0.

[image: Binarize Image]

```
RGB_Image = imread("RGB_Image.png");
Grayscale_Image = rgb2gray(RGB_Image);

imshow(Grayscale_Image);
Threshold_1 = 220;
Threshold_2 = 100;

Binary_Image = ((Grayscale_Image > Threshold_1) | (Grayscale_Image < Threshold_2));

subplot(1,2,1); imshow(RGB_Image);
title("RGB Image");
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Binary_Image);
title("Binary Image");
```

Comment: Did you copy the term "smart indexing" from the other answer? What does it mean? Where do you apply indexing?

Comment: That’s a term that does get thrown around sometimes interchangeably with logical indexing, which I realize isn’t proper/formal especially since weren’t grabbing the corresponding indices in this question .  I’ll fix that according to MATLAB’s documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use logical matrices.

```
b=(img>t1) | (img<t2);
```

Comment: it shows an error: `Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.`

Comment: mmm@CrisLuengo just ad hoc terms that I come about, shoudl change that

Comment: LOL. The other answer copied you ad hoc term. Maybe we should all start calling it that, see how long it takes for MATLAB to put the term in their docs!